# Windows 10: How do I fix a mouse stuck scrolling horizontally?

Tags: windows, scroll, driver, mouse, horizontal-scrolling

I had a mouse that was stuck scrolling horizontally.

It was constantly mimicking the behavior when a user holds down `shift` and scrolls the mouse wheel.  This made using the start menu, and other native Microsoft Store apps (e.g. GroupMe), very difficult.  It also caused many applications (e.g. Firefox) to change zoom levels when the control key was pressed.

I tried unplugging the mouse and using [Mouse Keys](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14204/windows-7-use-mouse-keys-to-move-mouse-pointer) to move the cursor.  The application under the cursor still horizontally scrolled.  I tried unplugging/replugging my keyboard if the `shift` key was stuck.  I looked at the Windows On-Screen Keyboard to see if it was registering a `shift` key as stuck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem was in the mouse driver.

1. Open the **Device Manager**.
2. Under **Mice and other pointing devices**, select/highlight **HID-compliant mouse** (or similar driver name).
3. Press the `delete` key to remove the driver.
4. Unplug/replug the mouse and let Windows re-install the driver.

The problem was resolved immediately.

Answer (score 0):

For those unsure about the reg key adding: run regedit, navigate to [HKLM\SOFTWARE\Synaptics\SynTPEnh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMzcc.png)

in left pane, right click SynTPEnh, select New/DWORD Value. Name of the new key should be writable, Name it: UseScrollCursor , value should be zeros at default, no need to change (in my case).

It's supposed to look like this: (at least it works in my case, no scroll sign after reboot at all... ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 mice plugged in, maybe a wired and wireless, unplug the second mouse. I unplugged my wireless mouse dongle to see if that solved the issue. It did for me. When I plugged the dongle back in, all was well. No more unwanted horizontal or vertical autoscrolling issues.